# How to set value for KeyboardDatePicker?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui, datetimepicker, react-datepicker

I have a form which containts material ui KeyboardDatePicker and as default value I want to use value from the Json response object. Here is the implentation:

```
 const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    console.log(date);
    setSelectedDate(date);

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(formData);

        axiosInstance.put(`admin/edit/` + id + '/', {
            title: formData.title,
            slug: formData.slug,
            author: 1,
            description: formData.description,
            content: formData.content,
        });
        history.push({
            pathname: '/admin/',
        });
        window.location.reload();
    };

<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                        <KeyboardDatePicker
                        label="Material Date Picker"
                        value={formData.start_date}
                        onChange={handleDateChange}/>
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

I am getting the next warning : `A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled.` and the label of input covers the value of the field.

[image]

how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Pulled from their documentation. Does this help ?
You were typing into the field but the value was not being set correctly. So the field never updated its value and never erased its label from the screen.

```
function ControllingProgrammaticallyExample() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState("2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");

  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <Button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}> Open picker </Button>

      <DatePicker
        variant="inline"
        open={isOpen}
        onOpen={() => setIsOpen(true)}
        onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}
        label="Open me from button"
        format="d MMM yyyy"
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: when I make implementation like this :  `const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(formData.start_date);
    const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    console.log(date);
    setSelectedDate(date);
  };`    `value={selectedDate}`   I get Invalid Data Format error.